# Parenthesis for arguments before blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, block

I notice that I need to put parenthesis around arguments I pass to a Ruby method before the block. Wat is the reason for that? Boiling down to the smallest example to illustrate what I mean:

```
def test a
   yield 100
end

test 50 { |x| x*x + 2 } # Gives an error in irb!

test(50) { |x| x*x + 2 } # Gives no error!
```

I didn't understand why Ruby complains about the first case. The error is along the lines of:

```
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):18: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the fact that `{`...`}` sometimes delimits a block and sometimes a Hash literal. Disambiguating those two uses has some odd side-effects.

If you use `do`...`end`, it works without the parentheses:

```
test 50 do |x| x*x + 2 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of the possible ambiguity that would arise:

```
def foo(val = "default", &block)
  # ...
end
```

Both hash and block literals are created using `{ ... }`

So if you call `foo {}` -  Are you passing an empty hash to the `val` parameter (with `block` becoming `nil`), or are you passing an empty block to the `block` parameter (with `val` becoming `"default"`)?

Comment: True, but in OP's case, a hash would be the second argument and would therefore require a comma between it and the first.

Comment: @MarkReed Yeah, OP's case wouldn't be ambiguous. I'm just showing that there are ways of defining a method that would be ambiguous.

Comment: I actually tried `foo {}`. It thinks of it as a block. In 2.1.4 at least. That's weird anyway =\

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't know what you want to do with the block.

When Ruby sees:

```
test 50 { |x| x*x + 2 } # Gives an error in irb!
```

It thinks that the block is attached to `50`, which is why you get the error.

When you put `50` in parenthesis, Ruby knows that the block is not binding to `50`.

```
test(50) { |x| x*x + 2 } # Gives no error!
```

For sanity, 99.9% of the time I put the parameters inside parenthesis. I don't like having to remember the rules for binding and that ensures that Ruby will do the right thing. Also, the parenthesis help us see what are the parameters, which aids in debugging.

Answer (score -2):

When using the block notation, the block is run against the value to the immediate left of the opening `{`.  So in your first example, you are attempting to pass `50 { |x| ... }` into the `test` method.  Since `50` is not an Enumerable object, you are getting an error.

Comment: You don't need an Enumerable to pass a block - you can pass a block to any method (even methods which don't expect blocks)